# Salesforce - Dynamically Copy fields to another custom field in a custom object

Tags: javascript, salesforce, custom-fields, apex, force.com

I have created a custom object with custom fields. I have a custom fields which gets some value. I want that custom field value to be copied to another custom field of the same custom object. I want this to be dynamic. I can achieve this through workflow or trigger but I wanted this to happen when a check box is checked. Based on user interaction, in the edit mode this function to be added. How can I achieve this? Suggestions please

Comment: Why you don't want to use before insert / before update trigger or workflow with field update action? You can implement a validation for checkbox in both cases.

Comment: Only option I see is to create a visualforce page and add some javascript to make it realtime.